# Video picture is not displaying in MS Edge Browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jwplayer

I have implemented JW Player to play video in ASP.NET MVC application, it plays video in all browsers except MS Edge Version 38.XXXX. It plays, however I am not able to see the picture.

Below is the library I am referring

```
   <script src="@Url.Content("//content.jwplatform.com/libraries/7GoBfbt6.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced existing (above) CDN with

```
  https://content.jwplatform.com/libraries/Z1S8LGzr.js
```

& it’s working fine in all the browsers including MS Edge (38.XXXX). Please create account in www.JWPlayer.com & get the latest CDN.